# Programmatic Insertion of Controls into a Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a for loop which I'm attempting to use to generate and lay out the contents of a Form.

This is what I've gotten to so far:

```
    public void RefreshSkillDialog()
    {
        Point nPt = new Point(25, 25);
        for (int x = 0; x < Enum.GetNames(typeof(Character.Skill)).Length; x++ )
        {
            GenerateFields(x,nPt);

            Console.Write(this.Controls.Count + "\n");

            Console.WriteLine(this.Controls[x].ToString() + "\n");
        }
    }

    public void GenerateFields(int it, Point pt)
    {
        Label tLbl = new Label();

        tLbl.Location = new Point(pt.X + (it * _vSpace), pt.Y);
        tLbl.Name = Enum.GetName(typeof(Character.Skill), it);
        tLbl.Text = this.Controls.Count.ToString();
        this.Controls.Add(tLbl);
    }
```

_vSpace is an integer initialized to 10 in the constructor.

The result of this code is:

[image: result of code]

I thought the issue was in reusing the tLbl variable, but as far as I can tell, it should work fine since I'm re-initializing it at the beginning of every iteration.

Comment: What's the result of `Enum.GetNames(typeof(Character.Skill)).Length`?

Comment: The return is the number of values in the Skill Enumerator. At the moment, the length returns as three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new `Label`, it is 100px wide by default.

You're changing the location (x-coordinate) of each new `Label`, but not by enough. Each new `Label` is overlapping the previous one, such that's it's covering up the text.

You can fix this by setting `AutoSize = true` on each `Label`:

```
Label tLbl = new Label();
tLbl.AutoSize = true;
...
```

Or by resizing it so that it's not as wide:

```
Label tLbl = new Label();
tLbl.Size = new Size(10, 23);
...
```

You might also consider just using a `FlowLayoutPanel`, since it will handle the layout for you. Add each new control to it, and don't bother with setting a `Location`.

```
Label tLbl = new Label();
tLbl.Name = Enum.GetName(typeof(Character.Skill), it);
tLbl.Text = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count.ToString();
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(tLbl);
```

If you do that, you'll have to change your `Console.WriteLine` statement in the other method too:

```
Console.WriteLine(flowLayoutPanel1.Controls[x].ToString() + "\n");
```

Comment: Leave it to me to overlook something this trivial. Thanks for taking the time. As a future reference, is this happening because labels are opaque?